# Azure - azure traffic manager vs azure traffic manager profile?

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

What is the difference between azure traffic manager vs azure traffic manager profile? All the available samples are based on azure traffic manager profile. Do we have azure traffic manager separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both refers to the same, its just the naming convention. When you create a new Traffic Manager it is named as Traffic Manager Profile, Like when you create a Cosmosdb it is named as Cosmosdb account.

Traffic Manager profiles use traffic-routing methods to control the distribution of traffic to your cloud services or website endpoints.

Comment: Thank you,Sajeetharan. Can we have multiple FQDN configured and each one would point to the individual web application? Eg: Adding multiple custom Domains in App Gateway using RoutingRule.

Comment: yes you can achieve this. I would recommend you to explore azure front door which comes with more advanced features for geo replicated application